# How to create simple restful login system in django?

Tags: django, rest

I want to create simple restful login system in django. I searched every where they are creating rest-full login system using Restful Framework. How to create without using any rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

Though the default authentication views in Django are not RESTful, you can use third party addons that extend the default views.

**[Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser)** works with Django Rest Framework and provides most of the endpoints for login system.

You can find the other options that work with most Django REST frameworks here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages